# Why use git rm instead of rm'ing files, directories, etc. and then using git add -u?

Tags: git, rm

I'm having trouble getting `git rm` to delete a now superfluous directory and it's files from a project. This made me wonder why `git rm` is the accepted practice when deleting tracked files instead of `rm -rf` the directory and files outside of git and then `git add -u` to stage and prepare deletion of the previously tracked files? The latter seems to make much more sense to me but I probably dont understand the advantages of `git rm`.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html)? Unlike `rm -rf` `git rm` has a number of options that might be handy for managing files in git your repository.

Comment: What problems are you having with `git rm`? It should just work and it's a single command rather than two.

Comment: Ok misunderstanding on my part, I was expecting to be able to `git rm` a directory when obviously git tracks the files only. A `git rm` of each file in the directory then removes the directory so all good.

Comment: @AndyBowskill: just like `rm`, you can use `-r` with `git rm` to recursively remove all files from one or more directories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, there are always multiple ways to do something. Some advantages that using `git rm` has, are:

- You actually control the index, not the real file system. The fact that Git removes the file in the file system as well is just a utility.
- This means that you can remove files from Git without deleting them: `git rm --cached`.
- You can precisely remove only those files you really want to be removed, unlike `git add -u` which adds all changes to the index.

Especially the last one is very important to me personally, as I want full control about what change I add to a commit. So using `add -u` will rarely make me happy (just like `add .`). But of course, if you are happy with using `add -u`, feel free to use it.

Comment: Thank you, very succinct and I can appreciate `git rm` now.